# Using REPLACE in MySQL is not actually replacing row

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

This is my current table with some rows in it:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_versus` (
  `id_user_versus` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user_winner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user_loser` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_versus` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user_versus`),
  KEY `id_user_winner` (`id_user_winner`,`id_user_loser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

INSERT INTO `user_versus` (`id_user_versus`, `id_user_winner`, `id_user_loser`, `id_user`, `date_versus`) VALUES
(1, 6, 7, 1, '2013-10-25 23:02:57'),
(2, 6, 8, 1, '2013-10-25 23:02:57'),
(3, 6, 9, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:04'),
(4, 6, 10, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:04'),
(5, 6, 11, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:10'),
(6, 6, 12, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:10'),
(7, 6, 13, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:18'),
(8, 6, 14, 1, '2013-10-25 23:03:18'),
(9, 7, 6, 2, '2013-10-26 04:02:57'),
(10, 8, 6, 2, '2013-10-26 04:02:57'),
(11, 9, 8, 2, '2013-10-26 04:03:04'),
(12, 9, 10, 2, '2013-10-26 04:03:04'),
(13, 9, 11, 2, '2013-10-26 04:03:10');
```

Now, I want to insert or replace the last row with this query:

```
REPLACE INTO user_versus (id_user_winner, id_user_loser, id_user) VALUES (9, 14, 2)
```

When I do that, instead of replacing the last row (that holds those exact values) it is adding a new row. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not specifying the primary key, which is `id_user_versus` in your insert.

Perhaps you intend to have a unique key (rather than just a standard key) across `id_user_winner` and `id_user_loser` in which case your replace would work to replace the row with those values.

Comment: This was the most complete answer. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE` uses `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`'s (unique indexes) to determine which rows are 'duplicate'.

In your table the only unique constraint is the PRIMARY KEY, and it is not specified in the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) "matches" on the `PRIMARY KEY` (or `UNIQUE` index) of the table. I don't see your primary key (`id_user_versus`) in your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` statement only replaces a row if an existing row with the same primary key and unique keys is found.

The MySQL documentation specifies:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html

The primary key in this table is not specified in your query, so it won't replace that row.